# Solve the limit of the following integral

Tags: limits, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral

Solve:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{n \sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}\,\mathrm dm(x) $$

I am aware that the problem should be solved by using the *Lebesgue's theorem of dominated convergence*, and the dominated function could be $g(x) = \frac{n}{x(1+x^2)}$ but the point $0$ gives me headaches.

How could I solve problems like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is the right one, but you have to use a stronger approximation than only $|\sin(x)|\leq 1$. For instance, using $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$, you get $$\left|\frac{n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}\right|\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}\in L^1(0,\infty ).$$

Comment: Great. Though, I am still confused when I substitute the limit and the integral, is the point $0$ still a problem? I am aware that the singularity at zero is of the first kind and limit at $0$ is equal to $1$, so the integral at zero is measure of the set $[0, \infty)$ which is not finite. Though, $0$ is just a singly point, but still is it a problem?

Comment: @NemanjaBeric: I don't understand the question $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(1+x^2)}=\frac{1}{1+x^2},$$ so no problem at $0$.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.